# Webkit browsers not rendering position: relative correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have a site which IE and FF render correctly but Chrome and Safari do not.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="cover">
</div>
<div class="nav">
</div>
<div class="misc">
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.cover{
position:absolute;
background-color:#00c9f8;
z-index:600;
height:100%;
}
.nav{
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
z-index:500;
}
.misc{
position:relative;
top:100%;
height:80%;
min-height:300px;
width:100%;
padding:0;
}
```

It would be expected that `.cover` will fill 100% of the viewport, which all browsers render correctly; `.nav` will be fixed at the top, which all browsers render correctly; and `.misc` will sit just off the viewport, which IE and FF renders correctly but Chrome and Safari do not. Webkit browsers instead make `.misc` sit at the top as if it had `position: fixed`.

In the example above `.misc` represents `.orbit-wrapper` in the actual site. Also the same problem exists for `.menu-box-row`, in which `position: relative` is not rendered correctly.

Many thanks in advance for a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentage values used with relative positioning have been an issue in Webkit for awhile. You should be able to find a workaround by changing the .orbit-wrapper's position to absolute and then tweaking the other elements' styles accordingly to account for the disruption in your flow. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! Changed most of the `position: relative` elements to `position: absolute` and adjusted it to fit the flow. I never knew this was a Webkit problem until now! Do you know if they are going to fix it any time soon?

Comment: They're working on it, but these issues date back a few years so I wouldn't hold your breath...

Comment: Hmmm, what a shame. Absolute positioning has ruined the responsiveness of the site, as elements are pulled from the normal flow so some elements start overlapping once the viewport size changes. :(

Comment: Found a fix to my problem that also kept the responsiveness! It'll take a while to explain and won't be particularly helpful to anyone so I'll save my breath (or keystrokes) :)